# Android App to clear GPS Ephemeris data

Tags: android, gps

I'm looking for a way to clear only the GPS [Ephemeris](http://www.how-gps-works.com/glossary/ephemeris-data.shtml) data after getting a location.

I know in the API there is a Android.Location.reset() function.  Is this the function I'm looking for?

EDIT: The concept is to simulate what happens to the GPS/location system when the phone is restarted without actually restarting the phone.

Answer (score 0):

The GPS device is separate from the cpu as is its software.  I know of no gps device which allows you to clear the ephemeris data. The bigger question is why would you want to do this? There seems to be no logical reason to me.

Comment: The idea is to simulate a GPS cold start -- as if the user restarted their phone, but without actually having to restart the phone.  It's for testing purposes (likely no practical everyday application).

Answer (score -1):

Programmatically you can't. Would it be good to let you clear that data when other apps may want to use gps? I believe it may be reset when the user reboots the phone though.

Now with a rooted phone I'm sure you could do it.

Comment: There is an app called **[GPS Status & Toolbox](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2&rdid=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2)** that I believe clears the Ephemeris data.  In the app if you go to **Settings > Tools > Manage A-GPS** state there is a reset feature.